# Using a variable in the INSPECT clause

Tags: cobol

I'm trying to use the INSPECT clause to see if a name (PIC X) contains a certain substring.

When I use

```
INSPECT NAME TALLYING COUNTER FOR ALL "lee"
```

The program works as expected,

When I replace the "lee" with a variable the command doesn't find anything.

```
...
WORKING-STORAGE SECTION.
   01  ZOEKTERM   PIC X(40).
...
MOVE "lee" TO ZOEKTERM
INSPECT NAAM TALLYING COUNTER FOR ALL ZOEKTERM
```

Can anyone explain why this is happening and what I can do about it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The fix is to explictly specify the length.

```
...
WORKING-STORAGE SECTION.
   01  ZOEKTERM   PIC X(40).
   01  ZOEKTERM-LEN PIC S9(4) COMP.
...
MOVE "lee" TO ZOEKTERM
MOVE 3 TO ZOEKTERM-LEN 
INSPECT NAAM TALLYING COUNTER FOR ALL ZOEKTERM(1:ZOEKTERM-LEN)
```

Comment: Beat me to it by a couple of seconds... +1

Answer (score 1):

The literal 'lee' is three characters long, while the ZOEKTERM is 40 characters long.

That affects the substrings they can match.

Answer (score 1):

Bo Persson is correct.  If you read the "Comparison cycle" in the [documentation](https://www.ibm.com/docs/en/cobol-zos/6.3?topic=statement-comparison-cycle), you will see

> The first comparand is compared with an equal number of leftmost contiguous character positions in the inspected item. The comparand matches the inspected characters only if both are equal, character-for-character.